# Conditionally specifying an option argument

Tags: cmake

I have a function in cmake which evaluates its arguments with `cmake_parse_arguments`:

```
function(example)
  set(options OPTION_A OPTION_B)
  set(one_value ONE)
  set(multi_value)

  cmake_parse_arguments(ARGUMENT "${options}" "${one_value}" "${multi_value}" ${ARGN})

  message(STATUS "Option: A:${ARGUMENT_OPTION_A} B:${ARGUMENT_OPTION_B}")
  message(STATUS "ONE: ${ARGUMENT_ONE}")
endfunction()
```

Is there a way to conditionally specify options without writing two separate calls?

This is fine for one option:

```
option(ENABLE_OPTION_A "Control option a" TRUE)

if (${ENABLE_OPTION_A})
    example(OPTION_A OPTION_B ONE 2)
else()
    example(OPTION_B ONE 2)
endif()
```

Now if `OPTION_B` were to also be conditionally specified it can quickly explode in complexity and results in a lot of duplication.

I know I could make the options take a single value like `ONE` in the example above but that kinda defeats the point of options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So just set a variable.

```
set(arg)
if(ENABLE_OPTION_A)
    set(arg OPTION_A)
endif()
example(${arg} OPTION_B ONE 2)
```